# Connecting Spring batch to Spring integration workflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to combine Spring Batch and Spring Integration in one project. So my idea is that Spring Batch using `StepBuilderFactory` reads the file with a custom method returning a `String` while the `.processor` creates a new `Message<String>` using `MessageBuilder` and sends that message into a channel...
So from here Spring Integration connects to that channel and starts working its workflow..
Any idea how to accomplish this? since i'm not getting any results besides getting the read `String` to the `.processor` but i can't reach Spring integration from there.
I read about the `remotechunkingmanagerstepbuilderfactory` but it's not suited for my purposes because it sets automatically a specific type

```
 @Bean
    public TaskletStep managerStep() throws Exception {

        return managerStepBuilderFactory.get("managerStep")
                .<String, String>chunk(5)
                .reader(readFile())
                .processor(new MessageProcess())//write String into Message and send it to Channel
                .writer(doSomething())//not important
                .build();
    }

public class MessageProcess implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String process(String readString) throws Exception {
        Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(item).build();
        channel().send(message); //sending message to channel
        return "item";

    }
}

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow workflow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(channel())
                .handle(checkMessage()) //checkMessage reads payload from Message<?> message
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel channel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

Comment: What the problem do you face with your `MessageProcess`? Doesn't look like there is something wrong. Although I would make that `MessageProcess` as a `@Bean`. Also be sure that you have a `@EnableIntegration` annotation somewhere on your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I agree with Artem. And in addition to that, why does the processor do 2 things and the writer does nothing? I would use the processor to transform the string into a message and the writer to send the message to the channel.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You were right. The code as it is works fine. I just forgot some annotations as @Artem Bilan suggested. I will accept that as the answer if you post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Spring Integration works with annotation configuration or Java DSL, you need to be sure that you specify an `@EnableIntegration` on some your `@Configuration` class. Or consider to use Spring Boot.

See more info the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration